# wxPython inputs layout

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new to wxPython and have some issues on adjusting dimensions of wxPython widgets. I am using `GridBagSizer` and would like to span some of my inputs.

For instance, I would like:

1. `self.combo` across 5 columns
2. `self.input2` across 5 columns
3. `self.input4` across 10 columns

I tried to use `span` but failed... I appreciate any suggestions!

```
import wx

class landing_frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):    
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size(800, 600), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.font1 = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.BOLD) 
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()     

    def InitUI(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 15)

        self.text1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Welcome!")
        self.sizer.Add(self.text1, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, border=15)

        line = wx.StaticLine(self.panel)
        self.sizer.Add(line, pos=(1, 0), span=(1, 5), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)

        self.text2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Question 1?")
        self.sizer.Add(self.text2, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.ALL, border=10)

        self.sampleList = ['Op1', 'Op2', 'Op3']
        self.combo = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, 10, choices=self.sampleList)
        self.sizer.Add(self.combo, pos=(2, 1), span=(1, 5), flag=wx.ALL, border=10)

        self.input1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, 11, label="Please Enter Filepath")
        self.sizer.Add(self.input1, pos=(3, 0), span=(1, 1), flag=wx.ALL , border=10)

        self.input2 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self.panel, 12, wx.EmptyString, u"Select a file", u"*.*", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE )
        self.sizer.Add(self.input2, pos=(3, 1), span=(1, 5), flag=wx.ALL, border=10)

        self.input3 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, 13, label="Additional inputs")
        self.sizer.Add(self.input3, pos=(4, 0), flag=wx.ALL , border=10)

        self.input4 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, 14, 'E.g. ...', wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.sizer.Add(self.input4, pos=(4, 1), span=(1, 10), flag=wx.ALL, border=10)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False, filename="mylogfile.txt")
    landing_frame(None, title="Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: If you want to have the widgets stretched, use wx.EXPAND (as you have on the StaticLine). If you want certain row or column wider or thicker, use self.sizer.AddGrowableCol(3) or AddGrowableRow.

Comment: @PetrBlahos, thanks. I guess `span` only works when `wx.EXPAND` is mentioned, right?

Comment: No, no. Span always works. But the widget only takes up as much space as it should. When there is no EXPAND, widgets tend to stay smaller.